# how to pass list variable in teradata sql in sas?

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

i have sas table containing id column and I am querying teradata sql with condition for sql table to have same id as the sas table. I use code below:

```
libname ss"dir";
proc sql;
connect to teradata(server);
crreate table ss.new as select * from connection to teradata(
select some from new_db where id in (select id from ss.table));
```

The code is not recognizing ss library. How can i pass the column as sql parameter ?

Comment: You need to create a libname connection to your teradata database, then create your ss.table in teradata (as long as you have the ability to do so.). Then do the join in teradata and return your results to SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list of `ID` values is < 64K characters long you can use macro to generate a source code (code-gen) snippet for an explicit `IN` list.

```
%let ID_LIST = 0; * just in case;

proc sql noprint;
  * build the ID_LIST using INTO :<macro-var> syntax;
  select id into :ID_LIST separated by ',' from ss.table;

  connect to teradata(server);

  create table ss.new as
  select * from connection to teradata
  (
    select id, column1, column2, ...
    from new_db
    where id in (
      &ID_LIST    /* code-gen, SAS will resolve the ID_LIST before passing to Teradata */ 
    )
  );
```